# Unable to start services in CentOS using systemctl

Tags: centos

I am facing the following issue when trying to enable and start the Icinga2 service in CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core)

#### Without Sudo:

```
systemctl enable icinga2
```

> Error getting authority: Error initializing authority: Exhausted all available authentication mechanisms (tried: EXTERNAL, DBUS_COOKIE_SHA1, ANONYMOUS) (available: EXTERNAL, DBUS_COOKIE_SHA1, ANONYMOUS) (g-io-error-quark, 0)
>   Failed to execute operation: Operation not permitted

#### With Sudo:

```
sudo systemctl enable icinga2
```

#### Error:

> Failed to execute operation: Connection timed out

Comment: Check if dbus is running (`pgrep dbus`),

Comment: It shows the status 751

Comment: Have you looked in the log files? Should be in `/var/log/icinga2`.

Comment: None of the service like httpd is also not starting with systemctl